# I want to compare two strings in order to create a new string of missing elements found in string1 but not in the second

Tags: python-3.x, list

For example:

```
string1 = "Hi i wish you are doing well"
string2 = "Hi In yesterday match you played very good"

Output: "i wish are doing well"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In its current form, this is just a task, not a question. What have you tried, why did it fail? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you try to get the `difference` between theses two sentences?  If so, then it's easier to use `set` operation of `difference`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is not clear, so I just assume you try to get the `difference` between two strings.  Could you try this first?

```
from functools import reduce

>>> diff = reduce(set.difference, map(set, (string1.split(), string2.split())))

>>> diff
{'well', 'wish', 'i', 'doing', 'are'}   # you can convert to list
```